# Why is this query not working as it should

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to display search results based on users team. it works ok only if i search by customer name but when i search by home_phone then it displays records of other teams too

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName WHERE team = '".$team."' AND customer_name LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' OR home_phone LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' OR alt_phone LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
    $total_pages = $total_pages[num];   

    // Get page data
    $query1 = "SELECT * FROM $tableName WHERE team = '".$team."' AND customer_name LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' OR home_phone LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' OR alt_phone LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' ORDER BY id DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query1);
```

appreciate your help

Comment: the lack of wrapping the ands and ors away from each other with parens?

Comment: Please use prepared statements to prevent sql injections (http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: sorry its home_phone

Comment: i know but its old script for offline purpose only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use brackets after `AND`:

```
 $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tableName WHERE team = '".$team."' AND (customer_name LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' OR home_phone LIKE '%".$srcquery."%' OR alt_phone LIKE '%".$srcquery."%') ORDER BY id DESC";
```

NOTE: all the `OR` statements should be inside a bracket.